# Format data for Google Charts in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am preparing data from Google Charts, but unable to create formatted data array for Google Chart.

I have array for object in this format:

```
[
    {
        "total_amount": 6572.67,
        "o_date": "2020-06-01",
        "storeName": "Store1"
    },
    {
        "total_amount": 314.21,
        "o_date": "2020-06-01",
        "storeName": "Store2"
    },
    {
        "total_amount": 5550.34,
        "o_date": "2020-06-02",
        "storeName": "Store1"
    },
    {
        "total_amount": 461.87,
        "o_date": "2020-06-02",
        "storeName": "Store2"
    },
    {
        "total_amount": 6471.37,
        "o_date": "2020-06-03",
        "storeName": "Store1"
    },
    {
        "total_amount": 547.99,
        "o_date": "2020-06-03",
        "storeName": "Store2"
    },
]
```

Google Chart needs data in this format:

```
['Store', 'Store1', 'Store2', { role: 'annotation' } ],
['2020-06-01', 6572.67, 314.21, ''],
['2020-06-02', 5550.34, 461.87, ''],
['2020-06-03', 6471.37, 547.99, '']
```

I tried different ways to make new array inside foreach loop, but could not format the array.
Can anyone please suggest me the right way?
Thank you.

**Update**

Thank you everyone for you comments and answers.

Yes, I am using PHP/Laravel.

To fetch the orders from database my query is:

```php
$orders =   $orders->select(DB::raw('SUM(orders.quantity) as total_quantity'), DB::raw('SUM(orders.totalAmount) as total_amount'), DB::raw('count(orders.id) as count'), DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') as o_date"), 'storeName')->groupBy('o_date', 'storeName')->get()->toArray();
```

The above query is returning array of objects as mentioned above. Than I extracted unique dates using `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($orders as $order)
{
    if(!in_array($order->o_date, $dates))
    {
        array_push($dates, $order->o_date);
    }
}
```

Then I am loop through all the dates like this

```
foreach($dates as $date)
{
    $dataArray[] = [$date];

    foreach($orders as $order)
    {
        if($order->storeName == $store && $order->o_date == $date)
        {
            $dataArray[] = [$date, $order->total_amount];

        }
    }
}
```

The above code is wrong. First element in the array should be **date**, second element should be **total_amount for store1** and third element should be **total_amount for store2** like below

```
['2020-06-01', 6572.67, 314.21, ''],
['2020-06-02', 5550.34, 461.87, ''],
['2020-06-03', 6471.37, 547.99, '']
```

**Note:- I am preparing data for [Google Stacked Column Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#stacked-column-charts)**

Comment: Ok, so how did you format the data like you have, did you do it using PHP? If so please show us

Comment: please show what you tried and describe what went wrong. Then at least we have a starting point and can try and fix it.

Comment: The data you have is in the json format you must use `json_decode()` to get the associative array.

Comment: Also your data does not look like the same data as you claim Google want

Comment: I think the OP knows that @KunalRaut What the question is about is getting data in a specific JSON format, which the OP has failed to achieve

Comment: total_quantity column is not for charts.

Comment: Show us **the code please**

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments/answers. @RiggsFolly please check my update in the question.

Comment: If the data going to Google is supposed to be JSON then what you show is Invalid JSON

Comment: I am preparing data for JSON output. I am trying to create array of data which Google Charts need. Please check my update in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little scrappy, but this should do it. The $chart variable will hold what you are looking for.

```
    // Assuming data is the "array for object in this format"
    $dates = array_reduce($data, function ($dates, $record) {
        if (!in_array($record['o_date']), $dates) {
            $dates[] = $record['o_date'];
        }

        return $dates;
    }, []);

    $stores = array_reduce($data, function ($stores, $record) {
        if (!in_array($record['storeName'], $stores)) {        
            $stores[] = $record['storeName'];
        }

        return $stores;
    }, []);
    
    $headers = $stores;
    $headers[] = [ 'role' => 'annotation' ])

    $chart = [ $headers ];

    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $datapoint = [ $date ];

        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            $total = 0;

            foreach ($data as $record) {
                $isStore = $record['storeName'] === $store;
                $isDate = $record['o_date'] === $date;
                if($isStore && $isDate) {
                    $total += (float) $record['total_amount'];
               }
            }

            $datapoint[] = $total;
        }
            
        $chart[] = $datapoint;
    }
```

Comment: `{ role: 'annotation' }` is going to get double-encoded when $chart is encoded as JSON. `['Store', 'Store1', 'Store2', array("role" => "annotation") ]` would be the correct way to express the structure in PHP.

Comment: @KunalRaut what makes this code produce static values, do you think?? It reads them from the original data array.

Comment: This `['Store', 'Store1', 'Store2', [ role => 'annotation' ] ]` doesn't seem dynamic at all

Comment: @ADyson these values are stored in the array as `storeName` have a look at them once.

Comment: @KunalRaut are you talking specifically about the header row? I see, it wasn't really clear from your comment before. I'd regard those as "headers" rather than "values".

Comment: @KunalRaut You did not post a very specific question. I think I see what you are looking for and how it should be structured. In the future, you should consider being specific in both questions and comments.

Comment: @KurtFriars I tried your answer. The output arrays only have dates. Please check output here. https://pastebin.com/bq37f9i1

Comment: I am trying to get the output in this format `['2020-06-01', 6572.67, 314.21, ''],
['2020-06-02', 5550.34, 461.87, ''],
['2020-06-03', 6471.37, 547.99, '']`

Comment: Looking at it again, I think I see that each date, should contain a value for each store. So let me update again.

Comment: Ok, I think that should be the data format you need.

Comment: @KurtFriars Perfect. Output is exactly the same as I need it. You saved my day. I was doing the foreach loop exactly the same way as you did, but was confused with `                    $isStore = $record['storeName'] === $store;
                    $isDate = $record['o_date'] === $date;
                    if($isStore && $isDate) {
                        $total += (float) $record['total_amount'];
                    }
' this part